# Account Locked in API Manager Store & Publisher 2.1.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there a way to lock a user's account after a certain number of failed login attempts to the API Store and API Publisher? I already check at FAQ API Manager, but then the documentation redirect to Identity Server files.

Its there any method on how to solve this issues?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the following properties in APIM_HOME/repository/conf/identity/identity-mgt.properties file.

> Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Failure.Max.Attempts

```
Authentication.Policy.Password.Expire.Time=0
# If account verification is not enabled, following property will decide where user must be lock or not after user is created 
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Creation=false
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.Time=0
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Failure=false
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Failure.Max.Attempts=0
```

Comment: But in API Manager 2.1.0 does not have this properties in their folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should first install following Identity Feature in WSO2 API Manager.

**Account Recovery and Credential Management**

**version :  5.7.5**

Then you will get the identity-mgt.properties file in your /repository/conf/identity directory.

By changing the following property value to the preferred number you can achive the account locking after several attempts.

`Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Failure.Max.Attempts=0`

**Note :**
To install the above feature,

- Login to Management Console of API Manager 2.1.0 (httpso://localhost:9443/carbon)
- Go to **Configure > Features > Repository Management** and add the following repository.
  http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/
- Then search for "Account Recovery and Credential Management Feature".
- Select and install the version 5.7.5 as below.[image]
- Restart the Server.